# How to deploy smart contract on Astar zkEVM testnet

Tags: zkevm, astar

I see that now Astar has testnet for zkEVM.

How do I deploy smart contract on it? Which infrastructure is supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for showing interest in deploying your product on Astar zkEVM Testnet.

Getting started on zKatana:

[Docs](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/zkEVM/quickstart)

[Explorer](https://zkatana.explorer.startale.com)

RPC: `https://rpc.startale.com/zkatana`

RPC: `https://rpc.zkatana.gelato.digital`

To get started, claim some free testnet ETH from Alchemy's [Sepolia faucet](https://sepoliafaucet.com/), bridge it using [zKatana L1/L2 bridge](https://bridge.zkatana.gelato.digital/), and you're ready to make your first Astar zkEVM transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!